# How to create bpmn2 process flow programmatically in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jbpm, bpmn

I use the Eclipse bpmn2 plugin :

[image]

To modelize my workflow:

[image]

How can we create workflows **programaticaly**, in something that looks like this:

```
public void CreateFlow() {
    StartEvent  StartEvent1;
    EndEvent    EndEvent1;
    Task        Task1;

    StartEvent1.linkTo (Task1);
    Task1.linkTo(EndEvent1);
}
```

Comment: Should noone help with _"The editor is fully customizable ..."_ there still is an alternative. Via the **XML** and **JAXB** I once made an intelligent viewer of BPMN2. A bit work, as there are several XML namespaces, and in my case the UI editor had its own objects tied to the flow/graph objects.

Comment: @JoopEggen You are right, it remains an alternative. But when I saw the structure of the XML files I was very quickly discouraged especially when I think that there is necessarily an API to do this...

Comment: Yes XML easily becomes bloated; I for instance found much redundancies. I did checks on cycles, unique branching conditions and such. BPMN is very well defined, so a viewer with a properties dialog was no problem. One week and about 50 classes. So the best would be to use their customisation/dev API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Fluent API [1][2] to programatically create process definition.
I am not sure if you can set X-Y coordinates of respective nodes, so can't confirm that importing *.BPMN file generated with this API into a BPMN designer will render properly - but it will be definitely executable.

[1] https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm/blob/master/jbpm-bpmn2/src/test/java/org/jbpm/bpmn2/ProcessFactoryTest.java#L70

[2] https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/release/7.33.0.Final/jbpm-docs/html_single/#_process_fluent_api

Comment: Thank you Anton, i'm trying this solution

Comment: trying out this i am not getting bpmn tags, just basic xml tag pattern is obtained.